# Is there a way to render an iframe inside of a PyQt5 application?

Tags: python, iframe, pyqt5

I'd like to know if there's a way to render an iframe inside of a PyQt5 GUI? I'd assume this would be done somehow through a QWebEngine widget

Comment: An iframe is just a way to show another webpage *inside* the current one, so you don't "show an iframe", you just show the content of the `src=` as a normal webpage. Just add a QWebEngineView in your ui and set its url to the src you want to display.

Comment: @musicamante Thank you for the clarification, I can now get any webpage inside of my GUI! I'm now wondering if you know if it's possible to get a local host server inside of a QWebEngineView widget? I've tried using the localhost url and it didnt work

Comment: Your question is unclear (and off topic, so you should probably create a question for it). Is the local server active? Does it work in a standard browser? Are you sure you're using the correct url?